# Select a custom column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to display a column which calculates two custom columns.

It look something like this

```
SELECT to_account as account, 
SUM(amount) total_claimed, 
COUNT(*) as transaction_count, 
((SELECT time FROM transactions WHERE to_account = account ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1) 
- (SELECT time FROM transactions WHERE to_account = account LIMIT 1)) / 3600 as interval_hours, 
(transaction_count / interval_hours) as avg_per_hour 
FROM transactions 
WHERE type='CLAIM' group by to_account ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

I get the message "Unknown column 'thetime' in field list"

How can I work with a custom column?

Comment: You cannot reuse a column you just made up by its alias (example: `(SELECT time FROM table ...) as thetime`, you cannot reuse `thetime` right away). You have to put it in a joined subquery, not an inline subquery.

Comment: Yeah, it's just the example, sorry. :)

Comment: One option is to rewrite your query -- move it to a subquery and then you can access the columns in an outer select statement.  There may be other options, but you'd need to supply additional information.

Comment: I'll just post the actual query.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Your full query needs a complete rewrite so while my example was good for the main idea of reusing columns, it was semantically not correct because your agregates need to be revised and I don't have time for it now.

Comment: Please share more details - the given query does not contain any occurence of `thetime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that using the column itself and not the alias since it's not accessible like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as amount, 
`time` as thetime, 
(`time` / amount) as average 
FROM table WHERE..
```

(OR) get it done in a outer query like

```
SELECT *, (thetime / amount) as average
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) as amount, 
(SELECT time FROM table ...) as thetime
 FROM table WHERE...)XXX;
```

Per your edited post, either you use the same expression again (OR) get the custom column in a outer query like

```
SELECT *, (transaction_count / interval_hours) as avg_per_hour
FROM (
SELECT to_account as account, 
SUM(amount) total_claimed, 
COUNT(*) as transaction_count, 
((SELECT time FROM transactions WHERE to_account = account ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 1) 
- (SELECT `time` FROM transactions WHERE to_account = account LIMIT 1)) / 3600 as interval_hours
FROM transactions 
WHERE type='CLAIM' 
group by to_account 
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
) tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using user defined variable,

```
SET @transaction_count := 0;
SET @interval_hours := 0;

SELECT to_account AS ACCOUNT, 
SUM(amount) total_claimed, 
@transaction_count := COUNT(*) AS transaction_count, 
@interval_hours := ((SELECT TIME FROM transactions WHERE to_account = ACCOUNT ORDER BY TIME DESC LIMIT 1) 
- (SELECT TIME FROM transactions WHERE to_account = ACCOUNT LIMIT 1)) / 3600 AS interval_hours, 
    (@transaction_count / @interval_hours) AS avg_per_hour 
    FROM transactions 
    WHERE TYPE='CLAIM' GROUP BY to_account ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```